# Delete retention policy for database with default true. What happens to the database retention policy in this case?

Tags: influxdb, retention

Delete retention policy for database with default true. What happens to the database retention policy in this case?

1. Step

   ```
   > show retention policies on market
   name       duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
   ----       -------- ------------------ -------- -------
   autogen    0s       168h0m0s           1        false
   exem_rp    672h0m0s 1h0m0s             1        true
   ```
2. Step 2

   ```
   > drop retention policy exem_rp on market
   > show retention policies on market
   name       duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
   ----       -------- ------------------ -------- -------
   autogen    0s       168h0m0s           1        false
   ```

Comment: Have you tried out what happens?

Comment: First, check that data is not retrieved (eg select * from tickers limit 3). I wonder what the retention policy during this time is.